# Does Firebird support Infinity as FLOAT value?

Tags: sql, floating-point, firebird

Firebird supports the special floating point value `Infinity` and `-Infinity` as `DOUBLE PRECISION` values:

```sql
select log(1, 1), log(1, 0.5), log(1, 1.5) from RDB$DATABASE
```

This yields

```
|LOG|LOG      |LOG      |
|---|---------|---------|
|NaN|-Infinity|+Infinity|
```

[The trick using `LOG()` with base `1` is documented here](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-log.html). While `NaN` also exists as a `FLOAT` value:

```sql
select cast(log(1, 1) as float) from RDB$DATABASE
```

The infinities can't be cast to `FLOAT`:

```sql
select cast(log(1, 1.5) as float) from RDB$DATABASE
```

I'm getting:

> SQL Error [335544916] [22003]: arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation; numeric value is out of range [SQLState:22003, ISC error code:335544916]

Is there any documented or undocumented way to get infinities of type `FLOAT` in Firebird?

Comment: there sems to be no such type as `real` - https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-datatypes-inttypes

it should be something of you own creation (SQL `DOMAIN`) not any Firebird's data type?

Comment: Good point. The SQL standard specifies `REAL`, `DOUBLE PRECISION` (both fixed precisions) and `FLOAT`, `DECFLOAT` types (with configurable precision). Some dialects use some of these types as synonyms for others. Firebird seems to do it, too. The term `REAL` is referenced further down in your link: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-structure-literals. Anyway, I'll update my question. It still holds for `FLOAT`

Comment: @Arioch'The Actually, there is a `REAL` in Firebird (since InterBase 6.0 AFAIK), it just wasn't ever documented, I fixed that in the Firebird 4 release notes. In Firebird `REAL` is a synonym for `FLOAT` (or - since Firebird 4 - `FLOAT(p)` with p <=24).

Comment: @LukasEder The term `real` in that section would more correctly be 'floating point', it doesn't refer to a SQL `REAL` as such.

Comment: @LukasEder that 2.4 table is not listing official type names, for example "binary string" and "null state", however it seems there is that type "unofficially"...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel does this query work for you on fb3? it works ok on fb2.1/ibexpert but somehow fails on DBFiddle `select log(cast(1 as float), cast (1.5 as float)) from RDB$DATABASE` https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=1706

Comment: @Arioch'The I thought it works, but that still produces a double precision as the result of `LOG` always is a double precision.

Comment: Yes, Double precision on fb2.1/ibexpert too. Just thought maybe it was some change in FB3 rather than dbfiddle obscure bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, it's complicated. Although Firebird's floating point types can hold/store NaN and Infinity in some cases, it doesn't support Infinity in casts to `FLOAT` (and as a result, neither for assignment conversions), because the cast to float performs a range-check, and -Infinity and +Infinity is out of range.

I'm not sure if that is intentional or not, but it probably is given how `CAST` is specified in the standard (though the behaviour for NaN is then questionable). In fact, I'm not even sure the support for NaN and Infinity is intentional behaviour, or just a side-effect of the underlying implementation supporting NaN and Infinity.

For example, it is possible to store infinity:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try (var connection = DefaultDb.createDefaultConnection();
         var pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into withfloat(floatval) values (?)")) {
        pstmt.setFloat(1, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        pstmt.execute();
    }
}
```

However, as far as I'm aware, there is no way to produce these values in DSQL itself.

I would recommend reporting this as a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE, but I'm not sure whether the bug is that it is possible to produce and store NaN/Infinity at all, or the behaviour of `CAST`. And I'm afraid fixing either is also problematic: disallowing is backwards incompatible, while allowing the `CAST` would violate the standard.

For the record, the SQL standard does not specify anything about NaN and Infinity for floating point types, but the rest of the specification make clear that NaN and Infinity should not be supported. For example, for `LOG` it specifies:

> 11. If <general logarithm function> is specified, then let VB be the value of the <general logarithm base> and let VA be the value of the <general logarithm argument>.
>     Case:
>     a) If at least one of VA and VB is the null value, then the result is the null value.
>     b) If VA is negative or 0 (zero), then an exception condition is raised: *data exception — numeric value out of range*.
>     c) If VB is negative, 0 (zero), or 1 (one), then an exception condition is raised: *data exception — numeric value out of range*._
>     d) Otherwise, the result is the logarithm with base VB of VA.

In other words `LOG(1, _)` should raise a *data exception — numeric value out of range* instead of producing NaN or +/-Infinity.

Comment: In similar vein, in Firebird 4 this also produces an error: `select cast(cast(log(1,1.5) as decfloat) as double precision) from rdb$database;`

Comment: I've created the following issue: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-6521. I think the `CAST` should work for consistency reasons, because the `NaN` cast already works, and because a lot of other RDBMS also support these extensions to the SQL standard